# How to add or remove partitions using the GParted partition manager?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

How can I remove a partition using GParted?

How can I create a new partition?

---

This is a Q&A *blog-like* question to describe the steps of the above operations. Feel free to refer anyone to this question or suggest edits on the comments.

Comment: Read the flipping manual provided by the developers? http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I remove a partition using GParted?

Follow these steps:

1. On the GParted main screen, select the drive from the *dropdown* list on the *top-right* corner of the GUI. By default GParted selects the first drive connected to your system, e.g. `/dev/sda`.
2. Once on the partitions scheme view you can select any partition you want either from the graphic at the top of the panel or from the list below it.
3. Right click the partition you want to remove and click *remove*. You can also *left-click* it on either view and press <kbd>Del</kbd>.
4. Press the *Apply changes* button on the toolbar at the top.

Now the space assigned to the recently deleted partition will be *freed* and marked as such.

> How can I create a new partition?

You can only create a partition out of the *free* space available on your drive, so you should either remove a partition to free some space (see above) or *resize* an existing partition. In the latter case follow these steps:

1. Right click the desired partition from either view and choose the *Resize/move* option from the context menu.
2. You can either use the graphical view to *pull back* your partition to the desired space or use the dimension spinners to specify the desired space, either *before* the partition with the *Precedent space* spinner or after it with the *Free space continuing* one. You can also specify a fixed size for the new partition and just pull the graphical view to either side of the graphic.
3. Press the *Apply changes* button on the toolbar at the top.

Note that moving a partition is an actual copy of information so it may take some time to complete the operation, a failure in the process may result in *data loss*, be careful.

Now that you have freed some space you can follow these steps to create your new partition:

1. Right click the desired free space to format on either view and click the *New* option on the context menu or just can just *left-click* it and press the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key.
2. You can then adjust the new partition's size like in the process above or leave it as it is to fill the space completely. You can also specify the desired filesystem and a label.
3. Press the *Apply changes* button on the toolbar at the top.

As a bonus, you can *wipe clean* all your partitions on your drive:

1. Select the *Create partition table…* option from the *Device* menu.
2. Select the new partition table format (usually *ms-dos*) and click Accept.

Now you have a clean drive so you can design your new *partition scheme* from scratch.

Important: All of the above steps are sensible to damage and as such, failure on any process may result in data loss.